# xargs misinterprets backslashes on windows

Tags: windows-7, xargs, gnuwin32

I am using gnuwin32 utilities on windows 7.

I want to pipe a file list to `xargs` to remove the files.

but if i pipe normal windows paths in then xargs interprets and removes the backslashes

```
dir /B /S c:\windows\system32\*.sys | head | xargs echo
```

results in the following input to `xargs`

```
c:\windows\system32\clfs.sys
c:\windows\system32\win32k.sys
c:\windows\system32\drivers\1394bus.sys
c:\windows\system32\drivers\1394ohci.sys
c:\windows\system32\drivers\acpi.sys
c:\windows\system32\drivers\acpipmi.sys
c:\windows\system32\drivers\adp94xx.sys
c:\windows\system32\drivers\adpahci.sys
c:\windows\system32\drivers\adpu320.sys
c:\windows\system32\drivers\afd.sys
```

that then prints

```
c:windowssystem32clfs.sys c:windowssystem32win32k.sys c:windowssystem32drivers1394bus.sys c:windowssystem32drivers1394ohci.sys c:windowssystem32driversacpi.sys c:windowssystem32driversacpipmi.sys c:windowssystem32driversadp94xx.sys c:windowssystem32driversadpahci.sys c:windowssystem32driversadpu320.sys c:windowssystem32driversafd.sys
```

with the backslashes removed.
So instead of simply outputting the input on the command line it parses and interprets the strings that I think it should not do.

How to work around this?

Comment: quote the file path. this is the standard approach to unescaping escape characters. I'm surprised however that you are not having issues with the switches in dir.

Comment: @FrankThomas i do no understand what you mean. the problem is not the `dir` command.

Comment: Do you get the same result if using GNU Parallel instead of xargs?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your findings on GNU Linux. Here the solution is to use GNU Parallel instead. So try using GNU Parallel:

```
dir /B /S c:\windows\system32\*.sys | head | parallel echo
```

It has been tested on CygWin, so it might just work on gnuwin32, too.

Comment: it seems that gnuwin32 does not contain `parallel` :-(

Comment: Easy to install: wget pi.dk/3; bash 3